# XCTAssertThrows stops at breakpoint

Tags: ios, xctest

I'm writing a test method where I want the SUT to throw an exception when under certain conditions. The code looks like this:

```
- (void) testCantStartTwice
{
    XCTAssertThrows([self.sut start], @"");
}
```

Now, all is good and the test passes. However, I have Xcode set an Exception Breakpoint for all ObjC exceptions, which is pretty useful when testing out an app in the debugger. As you now, now when I execute my test suite with ⌘U, now it stops at that test and looks like if it's failing, even though it says "Test Succeeded".

Any way of making the breakpoint **not stop** at that test?

Thanks and all the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it does not seem possible to have exception breakpoints ignore anything wrapped in `XCTAssertThrows` (or now `XCTAssertThrowsError`).

#### Workaround 1: Deal with the breakpoints or script around them

When you execute these tests, you can either do the following:

- Disable the exception breakpoint.
- Hit run every time it hits one of your breakpoints.

Both are not ideal as you'll be doing some manual work.

There are suggestions for [how to disable breakpoints for Swift XCTAssertThrowsError assertions here](https://gist.github.com/mattstevens/7463f5cfe21328c0e738d8e4ba674c7d). I have not tested those.

### Workaround 2: Return `Result<T, Error>` instead

My original method looked like this:

```
struct Truck {
  static func makeTruck(numberOfWheels: Int) throws -> Self {
    if numberOfWheels < 4 {
      throw TruckError.tooFewWheels
    }

    // ...

    return .init()
  }
}

// Code example:
let truck: Truck? = try? Truck.makeTruck(numberOfWheels: 1)

// Test example:
XCTAssertThrowsError(try Truck.makeTruck(numberOfWheels: 1))
```

To work around this problem of breakpoints, I created a duplicate internal function that is more testable (since it won't cause the breakpoint problem) by returning a `Result` instead of throwing an `Error`.

```
struct Truck {
  static func _makeTruck(numberOfWheels: Int) -> Result<Truck, Error> {
    if numberOfWheels < 4 {
      return .failure(TruckError.tooFewWheels)
    }

    // ...

    return .success(.init())
  }

  static func makeTruck(numberOfWheels: Int) throws -> Self {
    switch _makeTruck(numberOfWheels: numberOfWheels) {
    case .failure(let error):
      throw error
    case .success(let value):
      return value
    }
  }
}

// Code example:
let truck: Truck? = try? Truck.makeTruck(numberOfWheels: 1)

// Test example:
XCTAssertEquals(Truck._makeTruck(numberOfWheels: 1), .error(TruckError.tooFewWheels))
```

### Workaround 3: Return `T?` instead

Finally, if you have a simpler use-case, and your function's failure is quite obvious (e.g. there is only one type of error it can return), consider just returning an optional instead of needing the complexity of the `Result` type:

```
struct Truck {
  static func makeTruck(numberOfWheels: Int) -> Truck? {
    if numberOfWheels < 4 {
      return nil
    }

    // ...

    return .init()
  }
}

// Code example:
let truck: Truck? = Truck.makeTruck(numberOfWheels: 1)

// Test example:
XCTAssertNil(Truck.makeTruck(numberOfWheels: 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a Test Failure Breakpoint instead of an Exception breakpoint when you are testing. The wwdc 2013 video on unit testing outlined a pretty good workflow for inspecting test failures. It essentially said:

1. Set a Test Failure Breakpoint which will allow you to inspect the conditions that caused the failure.
2. If needed, set a manual breakpoint earlier in the test and rerun so you can step through the statements leading to the failure as usual.

This isn't really a direct answer, but as far as I know, I don't think there is a way to create exceptions to the exception breakpoint. Hope it helps

Comment: Ryan, thanks for the answer! That's a good solution, however, the exception breakpoint is really useful when executing the app on the Sim or Device. Ideally there should be a set of breakpoints when running and a set a breakpoints when testing, is there a way to set it up like that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I was looking for solution for 2 hours. Probably we can't do anything with that.